# Azure B2C password reset email

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We have been using Azure B2C for a little while now. The company recently went under a branding change (company name changed).

We updated the Azure AD to reflect this change. But we are also using Azure B2C for authentication, we have fully customized the login and password reset page. But we are having an issue with the email that gets sent out with the verification code for a password reset. It still has the old company name in the email subject, for example:

OLD COMPANY NAME account email verification code

Any idea on how to get these emails to update to the new Azure AD name? It doesn't seem to be stored in any application manifests, etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you should find the Company-Name mentioned under the  tag (can be found either in the base or extension custom policy file). Inside  tag, you should find a <InputParameter Id="Messages.0.Subject" ...> under the comment "Update with a subject line appropriate for your organization.". You can update the Company-Name value there.
This holds true for both MailJet and SendGrid email providers.
You can read more on this here:

**SendGrid:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email-sendgrid

**MailJet:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email-mailjet

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Azure Portal
2. Select your AAD B2C directory from the directory picker
3. Select the Azure AD blade
4. Select Properties
5. Change the directory name

This will reflect in the Azure AD B2C generated self service password reset email.